# Row Number with specific window size

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to group records by row numbers.

Like from row 1-3 in group 1 , 4-6 in group 2 , 7-9 in group 3 and so on.

Suppose below is the table structure:

<kbd>**`Row Number`**</kbd><kbd>**`Data`**</kbd><kbd>**`Value`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`10`</kbd>   
<kbd>`2`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>    
<kbd>`3`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`4`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`33`</kbd>   
<kbd>`5`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>    
<kbd>`6`</kbd>         <kbd>`A`</kbd>   <kbd>`127`</kbd>  
<kbd>`1`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd>    
<kbd>`3`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`7`</kbd>    
<kbd>`4`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`7`</kbd>    
<kbd>`5`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>    
<kbd>`6`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`8`</kbd>    
<kbd>`7`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`8`</kbd>         <kbd>`B`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd>

I want a output like this:

<kbd>**`Group`**</kbd><kbd>**`Value`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`10`</kbd>   
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`5`</kbd>    
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`33`</kbd>   
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`2`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`127`</kbd>  
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`0`</kbd>    
<kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`7`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`7`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`5`</kbd>    
<kbd>`2`</kbd>    <kbd>`8`</kbd>    
<kbd>`3`</kbd>    <kbd>`1`</kbd>    
<kbd>`3`</kbd>    <kbd>`0`</kbd>

**I am using Oracle 11G.**

I can achieve this using PL/SQL. But I have to use SQL only. As I have to use this query in a reporting tool.

If this is a duplicate question please provide the link of the answered question.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1 from the column `"RowNumber"` and divide by 3. 
Then use `TRUNC()` to get the integer part:

```
SELECT TRUNC(("RowNumber" - 1) / 3) + 1 "Group",
       "Value"
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=226c233daccead248ec293e4ac2e7561).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the name of the first column is `ordering`.

You can do:

```
select
  1 + trunc(row_number() over(partition by data order by ordering) - 1) / 3,
  value
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

What you show looks like the output from something like this:

```
select ceil(rn/3) as grp, value
from   your_table
order  by rn;
```

Note that "row number" and "group" are reserved words/phrases which should not be used as column names. I used `rn` and `grp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ceiling function is the simplest way to arrive at what you want.  If you want to base it on the `RowNumber` column:

```
select ceil( RowNumber / 3.0) as grouping
```

If you want to calculate it yourself using `row_number()`:

```
select ceil( row_number() over (order by RowNumber) / 3.0 ) as grouping
```